# Is there a way to activate a Google cloud service account non-globally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have such requirement to manipulate different services on different projects. Hence I need to activate multiple service accounts at the same time to do those jobs. Those service accounts' roles are well controlled so there's no way to make a "admin"-like account to run on all projects. So I'm wondering if there's a way to activate one service account only in current process or some isolated environment without impact on global `gcloud info` settings. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glcoud config configurations` and setup multiple account configurations to select from.

Then use the `--configuration=configuration_name` to select which one to use: `gcloud compute instances list --configuration=NAME`

Run `gcloud init` and select `Create a new configuration`.

You can change the default configuration with `gcloud config configurations activate NAME`.

I wrote an article that documents gcloud configurations:

[Google Cloud – Understanding Gcloud Configurations](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-understanding-gcloud-configurations/)

You can also activate service account credentials which will then be part of `gcloud config configurations`.

[Creating and Authorizing Service Account Credentials with the CLI](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-and-authorizing-service-account-credentials-with-the-cli/)

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account test@development-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=test_google_account.json
```

Comment: Thanks for advice! I went through your article just now but didn't find a method to parallel different service accounts. Concretely, what I'm looking for is to run program A using account `service_account_a`, which takes, say 30 mins to finish. Then run program B using another account `service_account_b` during the 30 mins. Is there a way to run B without failing A?

Comment: I just updated my answer. gcloud configurations support service account credentials also. You can then select which configuration you want to use. However, the application must support this feature. `gcloud` does, `gsutil` does NOT. For custom software, you need to hand code the method that selects credentials (if there are several) otherwise the current active credentials are selected by the google libraries.

Comment: I wrote a number of articles that go into detail about Google credentials, service accounts, etc. These articles might help you understand what they are, where they are stored and how to use them.